# Stuck in drawing using rectangular tool in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drawing

[image]

I want to draw a rectangle just like the size of the black background there, but it come out just like the white rectangle shown there. Even I have draw the white rectangle start from the top edge of the black background and drag it to draw the equal size, but it cant draw the precise size just like the black one.

It just like something stuck when I drawing. I draw the first rectangle, and if I drag a little bit more to larger the shape, it straight become like the second rectangle, different so much in height.

I wonder it is I have accidentally press any short-cut key and change some setting as it just suddenly happen when I can just draw other shape a minute ago without any problem.

May I know how to make it back to normal?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try snapping on and off

go to **view > snap to grid**

hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little difficult to understand, but you might find that turning on Smart Guides (View > Smart Guides) helps, as it will mean your drawing 'snaps' to the other shapes on your artboard.

It may also be that you have 'Align to Pixel Grid' ticked. Draw a shape, select it and then open up the 'Transform' palette and make sure that 'Align to Pixel Grid' isn't ticked. This feature is useful when designing pixel-perfect shapes for the web, but can sometimes mean that shapes move and warp after you've drawn them.